# Error in View : cannot coerce class ‘"infl"’ to a data.frame - Issue is with `infl` class

Tags: r, class, data-structures, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to view a collection of diagnostics using the `influence.measure()` function in the viewer above the console because to me it looks "cleaner". There's nothing special about the regression function, it is a basic multi-variate linear regression.

```
total_labour_hrs_lm = lm(data = Grocery_Retailer, formula = Total_Labour_hrs ~ Cases_Shipped + Labour_Hrs_Cost + Holiday)
```

```
> dput(head(Grocery_Retailer[, 1:4], 10))
structure(list(Total_Labour_hrs = c(4264, 4496, 4317, 4292, 4945, 
4325, 4110, 4111, 4161, 4560), Cases_Shipped = c(305657, 328476, 
317164, 366745, 265518, 301995, 269334, 267631, 296350, 277223
), Labour_Hrs_Cost = c(7.17, 6.2, 4.61, 7.02, 8.61, 6.88, 7.23, 
6.27, 6.49, 6.37), Holiday = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("data.data.data.data.1", 
"data.data.data.data.2", "data.data.data.data.3", "data.data.data.data.4", 
"data.data.data.data.5", "data.data.data.data.6", "data.data.data.data.7", 
"data.data.data.data.8", "data.data.data.data.9", "data.data.data.data.10"
), class = "data.frame")
```

After doing all of that I make the call to `influence.measure()`:

```
View(as.data.frame(influence.measures(model = total_labour_hrs_lm)))
Error in View : cannot coerce class ‘"infl"’ to a data.frame
```

This is the error I get. I was doing a little reading to try and get an idea of what is happening and I'm conjecturing it has to do with not being able to coerce the last column in the `influence.measure()` table into a structure that can be used in the `View()` function. Surely there must be a way around this because all the last column uses are `*` to identify the influential cases.

Still relatively new to programming so the ideas of classes, structures, etc is not formally understood yet and based off of what I've learned from doing all the work and practice I've done in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the model results and the `infl` object to get the data into the same format as you see when you run `influence.measures(model = total_labour_hrs_lm)`. You can just turn the first item in the list into a dataframe, then find the influential rows of data and `mutate` a new column with that information (i.e., *).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)

inflm <- influence.measures(total_labour_hrs_lm)

inflm.df <-
  as.data.frame(inflm[["infmat"]]) %>%
  tibble::remove_rownames() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(inf = ifelse(row_number() %in% unname(which(
    apply(inflm$is.inf, 1, any)
  )), "*", ""))
```

Output

```
         dfb.1_      dfb.Cs_S     dfb.L_H_    dfb.Hldy        dffit      cov.r       cook.d       hat inf
1   0.002676016 -0.0005907955 -0.004099162  0.00348584 -0.006017538 2.61954809 1.086293e-05 0.2085001    
2  -0.132020690  0.3163760133 -0.118513731  0.08050579  0.518084429 1.19096264 6.629460e-02 0.2000735    
3  -1.011752656 -0.2260721643  1.803437294 -1.06556827 -1.978217429 4.97708055 9.797699e-01 0.7978985   *
4   0.858588355 -0.8998589831 -0.357487343  0.06500172 -1.035351317 4.73921419 2.939023e-01 0.6947583   *
5   0.000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000000  0.00000000          NaN        NaN          NaN 1.0000000    
6  -0.027980403 -0.0014046128  0.059268845 -0.06382214  0.124813877 2.25009310 4.588414e-03 0.1437767    
7  -0.085471708  0.3210337973 -0.278119353  0.34105089 -0.529878642 2.16749365 7.637825e-02 0.3532302    
8  -0.454518871  0.4661922675  0.131276469  0.13744951 -0.611770744 1.44932953 9.444163e-02 0.2838286    
9  -0.062332350  0.0610196593 -0.002635099  0.07859391 -0.266734659 1.56401553 1.928013e-02 0.1173206    
10  0.974167713 -1.0201812141 -0.218184444 -0.41667266  1.544679713 0.03659811 2.467009e-01 0.2006134   *
```

Comment: Sleek. Thanks for this solution. Uses a few notions I don't fully grasp yet. But I have worked enough with tidyverse to work out the methodology.